# Default column for sorting in richfaces

Tags: richfaces, seam

I have the following environment: Seam 2.2.0 GA with default richfaces version.

How do I define a default column (field) for my datatable to sort the records by this field?
I tried setting a default value for the "sort" parameter in my .page.xml file but that didn't help.

In addition, my entityList.java returns NULL when System.out.println(this.getOrderColumn()); Does this mean that sorting happens at the client side? If so, why is the entityList() called each time I re-sort the list?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your EntityList class must extend from EntityQuery, so you can add these two lines in the constructor of EntityList:

```
setOrderColumn("yourEntity.property");
setOrderDirection("asc");
```

or just add one line:

```
setOrder("yourEntity.property asc");
```

I know this is hard-coded, bad but works. If anyone has a better way, please share with us. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer actually works ( with modifications in order to keep the possibility of sorting by other fields later on). However, I have fixed my problem by providing the sorting column and the sorting order in the query string in the <s:button><f:param> link button which takes me to that list's page. Thank you.